# Dynamic programming: minimum price for translating a number of books

Tags: algorithm

We have N books ( `N<=200` ). All of them must be translated by K people (`K<=100`).
Every man can translate D books starting from index S to index S+D-1, 0<=D<=N.
Every man is paid c_1 dolars per page for the first book which he translates, c_2 for the second...

```
c_i for the book i.
0<=c_i<10000
```

The books must be translated in the order they are given.

input:
first row: 2 numbers N and K
second row: N numbers - number of pages per every book (<=10 000)
third row: N numbers - c_1, c_2, ... c_N; c_i is the price for translating a book by a man who has translated i-1 books;

output:
minimum price which must be paid for the translation of all the books.

Example:
Input:
6 3
50 100 60 5 6 30
1 2 3 4 5 6

Output: 339
(the first man translated the first book +50*1
the scond man translated the second,third,forth and fifth books:
+100*1+60*2+5*3+6*4
the third man translates the last book
+30*1
=339)

Can someone help me with this homework? I know i must be using dynamic programming to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some clues: make a function F(BookNumber, ManNumber, NumOfBooksHeHaveTranslated).

Start with F(1, 1, 0). It is clear that

```
F(1, 1, 0) = Pages[1] * C[1] + Min(F(2, 1, 1), F(2, 2, 0))
```

i.e. we have to choose the best variant from - continue with the same translator, or use the next one. Elaborate this function for common case F(B, M, N), make recursive solution, check it for small inputs, transform recursion into DP (the methods are described in algo books)

Answer (score 0):

The actual choice your algorithm needs to do is at which points in the sequence of books you change from one translator to the next one. That's the only decision point for the problem, and everything else follows from it. You can translate this to a recursive / dynamic programming problem by observing e.g. that the cost of translating N books by K translators is equivalent to the cost of translating x first books by one translator and N - x by the remaining K - 1 translators; or, equivalent to the cost of translating x first books by n translators and N - x by the remaining K - n translators. This is a subdivision / recursion step that you can use in a dynamic programming solution.

I hope no-one will post actually code to do this; it is homework.